# when in heex to comment out line, html parse error appears

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to comment the follows heex file's `span` line according to the method in [elixir forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-can-i-easily-comment-out-lines-in-a-html-heex-file/43016/13)

When recompile. The error message is as follows:

```
macbook:pen yuchen$ mix compile
Compiling 1 file (.ex)

== Compilation error in file lib/pen_web/views/login_view.ex ==
** (Phoenix.LiveView.HTMLTokenizer.ParseError) lib/pen_web/templates/login/show.html.heex:11:42: expected closing `"` for attribute value

Make sure the attribute is properly closed. This may also happen if
there is an EEx interpolation inside a tag, which is not supported.
Instead of

    <div <%= @some_attributes %>>
    </div>

do

    <div {@some_attributes}>
    </div>
Where @some_attributes must be a keyword list or a map.

    (phoenix_live_view 0.17.11) lib/phoenix_live_view/html_tokenizer.ex:487: Phoenix.LiveView.HTMLTokenizer.handle_attr_value_quote/7
    (phoenix_live_view 0.17.11) lib/phoenix_live_view/html_engine.ex:122: Phoenix.LiveView.HTMLEngine.handle_text/3
    (eex 1.13.4) lib/eex/compiler.ex:49: EEx.Compiler.generate_buffer/4
    (eex 1.13.4) lib/eex/compiler.ex:82: EEx.Compiler.generate_buffer/4
    (phoenix_view 1.1.2) lib/phoenix/template.ex:419: Phoenix.Template.compile/3
    (phoenix_view 1.1.2) lib/phoenix/template.ex:197: anonymous fn/4 in Phoenix.Template."MACRO-__before_compile__"/2
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/enum.ex:2396: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (phoenix_view 1.1.2) expanding macro: Phoenix.Template.__before_compile__/1
** (exit) shutdown: 1
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:78: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.compile/4
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:59: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.with_logger_app/2
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:36: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run/1
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/task.ex:397: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/tasks/compile.ex:131: Mix.Tasks.Compile.run/1
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/task.ex:397: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (iex 1.13.4) lib/iex/helpers.ex:107: IEx.Helpers.recompile/1
```

`show.html.heex` file is as follows:

```
<h2>Log in</h2>
<%= form_tag(Routes.login_path(Endpoint, :create)) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username or Email</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <.ignore>
    <span style="float: right;"><a href="<%= Routes.password_reset_path(Endpoint, :show) %>">Forgot your password?</a></span>
    </.ignore>
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>

  <br><br>

<% end %>
```

`heexIgnore` file is as follows:

```
defmodule PenWeb.HeexIgnore do
  use Phoenix.Component

  def ignore(assigns), do: ~H""
end
```

Pen_web.ex file is as follows:

```
  defp view_helpers do
    quote do
      # Use all HTML functionality (forms, tags, etc)
      use Phoenix.HTML

      # Import LiveView and .heex helpers (live_render, live_patch, <.form>, etc)
      import Phoenix.LiveView.Helpers

      # Import basic rendering functionality (render, render_layout, etc)
      import Phoenix.View

      import PenWeb.ErrorHelpers
      import PenWeb.Gettext
      alias PenWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes
      alias PenWeb.{Endpoint, Router}
      import PenWeb.HeexIgnore
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think the error message is truncated, what comes before `Where @some_attributes ...`? Also, your syntax for HTML attributes seem wrong, `<a href="<%= ... %>"` should be `<a href={...}` I think ([difference between HEEx and the previous format LEEx](https://latuszewski.appunite.com/post/quick-migration-from-leex-to-heex))

Comment: That's the problem. I have copied the code from the hexpm, It seem strange why it can run before in my notework with the same elixir and phoenix version.

Comment: I have updated the post for missing truncated message. It is caused by the file difference. The orginal file's extension name is *.eex. The new file's extension name is "heex".